# Spring Security ignore path for filter

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt

How can I configure Spring Security to use a custom filter for all requests except the ones I whitelist in the **same level**, e.g. "/login" skips my filter but every thing else "/**" goes through the filter.

As a workaround I could use different prefixes, "/secured/**" vs "/whitelist/**" or ignore the whitelisted ones in the filter, but that does not seem to be a clean solution.

I already tried setting up two configurations with @Order(1 and 2) but it didn't work.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
    public static class JwsSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private StatelessAuthenticationFilter statelessAuthenticationFilter;

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
                    .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/login");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and().addFilterBefore(statelessAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }

        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return authenticationManager();
        }
    }
}
```